# Why can't we define a function using a type name?

Tags: c, function, types, language-lawyer, c11

Any ideas why can't we define a function using type name:

```
typedef int functype(int arg1);


functype funcdefinition {
    ;
}
```

But we can declare one this way:

```
functype funcdeclaration;
```

Comment: Where would the parameter names go?

Comment: @M.M They will be inherited from the type name. I highly doubt this would be too hard to implement.

Comment: If the type name used to declare the function haven't assigned name to some parameter then this parameter will not be accessible by name just like an unnamed temporary.

Comment: Or the compiler will report error.

Answer (score 1):

Standard says that (C11 section 6.9.1):

> The identifier declared in a function definition (which is the name of the function) shall have a function type, as specified by the declarator portion of the function definition<sup>162)</sup>

and the foot note 162 says:

> 162) The intent is that the type category in a function definition cannot be inherited from a typedef:
>
> ```
> typedef int F(void);          // type F is ‘‘function with no parameters 
>                               // returning int’’
> F f,g;                        // f and g both have type compatible with F   
> F f { /* ... */ }             // WRONG: syntax/constraint error  
> F g() { /* ... */ }           // WRONG: declares that g returns a function   
> int f(void) { /* ... */ }     // RIGHT: f has type compatible with F  
> int g() { /* ... */ }         // RIGHT: g has type compatible with F
> F *e(void) { /* ... */ }      // e returns a pointer to a function
> F *((e))(void) { /* ... */ }  // same: parentheses irrelevant
> int (*fp)(void);              // fp points to a function that has type F   
> F *Fp;                        // Fp points to a function that has type F
> ```

Therefore,

```
functype funcdefinition;
```

declares that `funcdefinition` is of type `functype`, which is correct. No need of the name of function parameters in function prototype. In case of

```
functype funcdefinition { ... }
```

parameter names are needed and there is no way to declare the names of function parameters and therefore it is an incorrect syntax.

Comment: Yeah any ideas why is this? I mean what's the problem of using type names for defining a function?

Comment: @FISOCPP Most likely just that they didn't see any reason to make it work.

Comment: @FISOCPP; Added explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a typedef for a function prototype, but not for a function body.

The typedef for `functype` (in the question above) is creating a typedef for a function prototype - not a function body.  In the "C" language, the function *with the function body included* will not evaluate to a valid type.  That is why the function body is not allowed.

**WHY doesn't the C language allow a type to contain a function body? Because:**

- When exact type checking is used with a function body type, the only types that **match** `functype` would have the **same body** as `funcdefinition`.
- With exact type checking, the function body data type could only point to a function with **exactly the same code**.
- If the function body were used in the type definition, then even a function with the same prototype (but a **different body**) will technically result in a type mismatch.  The current version of "C" is strongly typed.  Because "C and C++ (do) not let you use one type when another type is expected.", even if the C compiler were to include function bodies in a type definition (which it does not), the compiler would have no way of resolving differences in the function body other than to report the types do not match.

---

Although it is not as useful as having a typedef with a body, you **CAN STILL** create a **function pointer** using this typedef - and the C++ compiler will still check the argument list; see below:

```
typedef int functype(int arg1);

int f1(int arg1) {
    return arg1;
}
int f2(int arg1) {
    return arg1;
}
int f3(int arg1, int arg2) {
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    functype* pf1;
    pf1=&f1;           /* Compiles properly */
    pf1=&f3;           /* Will not compile, as expected */
                       /* because of an argument mismatch */
    return 0;
}
```

In this sense, using the typedef is helpful because it avoids the function pointer syntax.

REFERENCES:

http://www.drtak.org/teaches/modules/0027/module/node7.html

Answer (score 0):

When you define a function as

```
xxx myfunction(...) {}
```

you are stating that myfunction is a function that returns a xxx. For example,

```
int myFunc()[]
```

says that myFunc returns an int. Therefore

```
functype funcdefinition() { ... }
```

says that funcdefinition returns a functype, which (if your example were correct) would mean that it returns "a function that takes an integer argument and returns an int".

Comment: You are not answering my question and basically talking off-topic.